# What changed in exim 4.94, after update the line throws an error

Tags: exim, vesta

I use Vesta control panel, Exim is screwed to it, after update, errors.

```
2020-12-03 23:45:35 H=mail-wr1-f44.google.com [209.85.221.44] X=TLS1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=no F=<mymail@gmail.com> temporarily rejected RCPT <info@my.com>: failed to expand "${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/aliases}}}}": NULL
```

along the way there are symbolic links. How to zoom out?
/etc/exim/domains/$domain/aliases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Exim configuration for Centos 7/8

Search google: Devoleksiy vesta rhel8 exim.conf

```
######################################################################
#                                                                    #
#          Exim configuration file for Vesta Control Panel           #
#                                                                    #
######################################################################

#SPAMASSASSIN = yes
#SPAM_SCORE = 50
#CLAMD = yes

add_environment = <; PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
keep_environment =

disable_ipv6=true
domainlist local_domains = dsearch;/etc/exim/domains/
domainlist relay_to_domains = dsearch;/etc/exim/domains/
hostlist relay_from_hosts = 127.0.0.1
hostlist whitelist = net-iplsearch;/etc/exim/white-blocks.conf
hostlist spammers = net-iplsearch;/etc/exim/spam-blocks.conf
no_local_from_check
untrusted_set_sender = *
acl_smtp_connect = acl_check_spammers
acl_smtp_mail = acl_check_mail
acl_smtp_rcpt = acl_check_rcpt
acl_smtp_data = acl_check_data
acl_smtp_mime = acl_check_mime
.ifdef SPAMASSASSIN
spamd_address = 127.0.0.1 783
.endif

.ifdef CLAMD
av_scanner = clamd: /var/run/clamav/clamd.sock
.endif

tls_advertise_hosts = *
tls_certificate = ${if and \
{ \
{gt{$tls_in_sni}{}} \
{!match{$tls_in_sni}{/}} \
} \
{${if exists {/usr/local/vesta/ssl/exim.cert.$tls_in_sni} \
{/usr/local/vesta/ssl/exim.cert.$tls_in_sni} \
{/usr/local/vesta/ssl/certificate.crt} \
}} \
{/usr/local/vesta/ssl/certificate.crt} \
}

tls_privatekey = ${if and \
{ \
{gt{$tls_in_sni}{}} \
{!match{$tls_in_sni}{/}} \
} \
{${if exists {/usr/local/vesta/ssl/exim.key.$tls_in_sni} \
{/usr/local/vesta/ssl/exim.key.$tls_in_sni} \
{/usr/local/vesta/ssl/certificate.key} \
}} \
{/usr/local/vesta/ssl/certificate.key} \
}



openssl_options = +no_sslv2 +no_sslv3
tls_require_ciphers = ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:!DSS

daemon_smtp_ports = 25 : 465 : 587 : 2525
tls_on_connect_ports = 465
never_users = root
host_lookup = *
rfc1413_hosts = *
rfc1413_query_timeout = 1s
ignore_bounce_errors_after = 2d
timeout_frozen_after = 7d

DKIM_DOMAIN = ${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}
DKIM_FILE = /etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/dkim.pem
DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY = ${if exists{DKIM_FILE}{DKIM_FILE}{0}}



######################################################################
#                       ACL CONFIGURATION                            #
#         Specifies access control lists for incoming SMTP mail      #
######################################################################
begin acl

acl_check_spammers:
accept hosts = +whitelist

drop message = Your host in blacklist on this server.
log_message = Host in blacklist
hosts = +spammers

accept

acl_check_mail:
deny condition = ${if eq{$sender_helo_name}{}}
message = HELO required before MAIL

drop message = Helo name contains a ip address (HELO was $sender_helo_name) and not is valid
condition = ${if match{$sender_helo_name}{\N((\d{1,3}[.-]\d{1,3}[.-]\d{1,3}[.-]\d{1,3})|([0-9a-f]{8})|([0-9A-F]{8}))\N}{yes}{no}}
condition = ${if match {${lookup dnsdb{>: defer_never,ptr=$sender_host_address}}\}{$sender_helo_name}{no}{yes}}
delay = 45s
drop condition = ${if isip{$sender_helo_name}}
message = Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.3)

drop condition = ${if eq{[$interface_address]}{$sender_helo_name}}
message = $interface_address is _my_ address

accept

acl_check_rcpt:
accept hosts = :

deny message = Restricted characters in address
domains = +local_domains
local_parts = ^[.] : ^.*[@%!/|]

deny message = Restricted characters in address
domains = !+local_domains
local_parts = ^[./|] : ^.*[@%!] : ^.*/\\.\\./

require verify = sender

accept hosts = +relay_from_hosts
control = submission

accept authenticated = *
control = submission/domain=

deny message = Rejected because $sender_host_address is in a black list at $dnslist_domain\n$dnslist_text
hosts = !+whitelist
dnslists = ${readfile {/etc/exim/dnsbl.conf}{:}}

require message = relay not permitted
domains = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains



deny message = smtp auth requried
sender_domains = +local_domains
!authenticated = *

require verify = recipient

.ifdef CLAMD
warn set acl_m0 = no

warn condition = ${if exists {/etc/exim/domains/$domain/antivirus}{yes}{no}}
set acl_m0 = yes
.endif

.ifdef SPAMASSASSIN
warn set acl_m1 = no

warn condition = ${if exists {/etc/exim/domains/$domain/antispam}{yes}{no}}
set acl_m1 = yes
.endif

accept

acl_check_data:
.ifdef CLAMD
deny message = Message contains a virus ($malware_name) and has been rejected
malware = *
condition = ${if eq{$acl_m0}{yes}{yes}{no}}
.endif

.ifdef SPAMASSASSIN
warn !authenticated = *
hosts = !+relay_from_hosts
condition = ${if < {$message_size}{100K}}
condition = ${if eq{$acl_m1}{yes}{yes}{no}}
spam = spamd:true/defer_ok
add_header = X-Spam-Score: $spam_score_int
add_header = X-Spam-Bar: $spam_bar
add_header = X-Spam-Report: $spam_report
set acl_m2 = $spam_score_int
warn condition = ${if !eq{$acl_m2}{} {yes}{no}}
condition = ${if >{$acl_m2}{SPAM_SCORE} {yes}{no}}
add_header = X-Spam-Status: Yes
message = SpamAssassin detected spam (from $sender_address to $recipients).
.endif

accept

acl_check_mime:
deny message = Blacklisted file extension detected
condition = ${if match {${lc:$mime_filename}}{\N(\.ade|\.adp|\.bat|\.chm|\.cmd|\.com|\.cpl|\.exe|\.hta|\.ins|\.isp|\.jse|\.lib|\.lnk|\.mde|\.msc|\.msp|\.mst|\.pif|\.scr|\.sct|\.shb|\.sys|\.vb|\.vbe|\.vbs|\.vxd|\.wsc|\.wsf|\.wsh)$\N}{1}{0}}

accept



######################################################################
#                   AUTHENTICATION CONFIGURATION                     #
######################################################################
begin authenticators

dovecot_plain:
driver = dovecot
public_name = PLAIN
server_socket = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
server_set_id = $auth1

dovecot_login:
driver = dovecot
public_name = LOGIN
server_socket = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
server_set_id = $auth1



######################################################################
#                      ROUTERS CONFIGURATION                         #
#               Specifies how addresses are handled                  #
######################################################################
begin routers

#smarthost:
# driver = manualroute
# domains = ! +local_domains
# transport = remote_smtp
# route_list = * smartrelay.vestacp.com
# no_more
# no_verify

dnslookup:
driver = dnslookup
domains = !+local_domains
transport = remote_smtp
no_more

userforward:
driver = redirect
check_local_user
file = $home/.forward
allow_filter
no_verify
no_expn
check_ancestor
file_transport = address_file
pipe_transport = address_pipe
reply_transport = address_reply

procmail:
driver = accept
check_local_user
require_files = ${local_part}:+${home}/.procmailrc:/usr/bin/procmail
transport = procmail
no_verify

autoreplay:
driver = accept
require_files = /etc/exim/domains/$domain/autoreply.${local_part}.msg
condition = ${if exists{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/autoreply.${local_part}.msg}{yes}{no}}
retry_use_local_part
transport = userautoreply
unseen

aliases:
driver = redirect
headers_add = X-redirected: yes
data = ${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/aliases}}}}
require_files = /etc/exim/domains/$domain/aliases
redirect_router = dnslookup
pipe_transport = address_pipe
unseen

localuser_fwd_only:
driver = accept
transport = devnull
condition = ${if exists{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/fwd_only}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/fwd_only}{true}{false}}}}

localuser_spam:
driver = accept
transport = local_spam_delivery
condition = ${if eq {${if match{$h_X-Spam-Status:}{\N^Yes\N}{yes}{no}}} {${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/passwd}{yes}{no_such_user}}}}

localuser:
driver = accept
transport = local_delivery
condition = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/passwd}{true}{false}}

catchall:
driver = redirect
headers_add = X-redirected: yes
require_files = /etc/exim/domains/$domain/aliases
data = ${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{*@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/aliases}}}}
file_transport = local_delivery
redirect_router = dnslookup

terminate_alias:
driver = accept
transport = devnull
condition = ${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/aliases}{true}{false}}



######################################################################
#                      TRANSPORTS CONFIGURATION                      #
######################################################################
begin transports

remote_smtp:
driver = smtp
#helo_data = $sender_address_domain
dkim_domain = DKIM_DOMAIN
dkim_selector = mail
dkim_private_key = DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY
dkim_canon = relaxed
dkim_strict = 0

procmail:
driver = pipe
command = "/usr/bin/procmail -d $local_part"
return_path_add
delivery_date_add
envelope_to_add
user = $local_part
initgroups
return_output

local_delivery:
driver = appendfile
maildir_format
maildir_use_size_file
user = ${extract{2}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/passwd}}}}
group = mail
create_directory
directory_mode = 770
mode = 660
use_lockfile = no
delivery_date_add
envelope_to_add
return_path_add
directory = "${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/passwd}}}}/mail/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/${lookup{$local_part}dsearch{${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/passwd}}}}/mail/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}}}"
quota = ${extract{6}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/passwd}}}}M
quota_warn_threshold = 75%

local_spam_delivery:
driver = appendfile
maildir_format
maildir_use_size_file
user = ${extract{2}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/passwd}}}}
group = mail
create_directory
directory_mode = 770
mode = 660
use_lockfile = no
delivery_date_add
envelope_to_add
return_path_add
directory = "${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/passwd}}}}/mail/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/${lookup{$local_part}dsearch{${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/passwd}}}}/mail/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}}}/.Spam"
quota = ${extract{6}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/passwd}}}}M
quota_directory = "${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/passwd}}}}/mail/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/${lookup{$local_part}dsearch{${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}/passwd}}}}/mail/${lookup{$domain}dsearch{/etc/exim/domains/}}}}"
quota_warn_threshold = 75%

address_pipe:
driver = pipe
return_output


address_file:
driver = appendfile
delivery_date_add
envelope_to_add
return_path_add

address_reply:
driver = autoreply

userautoreply:
driver = autoreply
file = /etc/exim/domains/$domain/autoreply.${local_part}.msg
from = "${local_part}@${domain}"
headers = Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
subject = "${if def:h_Subject: {Autoreply: \"${rfc2047:$h_Subject:}\"} {Autoreply Message}}"
to = "${sender_address}"

devnull:
driver = appendfile
file = /dev/null

######################################################################
#                      RETRY CONFIGURATION                           #
######################################################################
begin retry

# Address or Domain Error Retries
# ----------------- ----- -------
* * F,2h,15m; G,16h,1h,1.5; F,4d,6h



######################################################################
#                      REWRITE CONFIGURATION                         #
######################################################################
begin rewrite



######################################################################
```